# changing base class from cdialog to cdialogex

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

```
class CSampleDlg : public CDialog
```

I have an MFC dialog based application in which dialog class extends CDialog.
 How can i change base class of my MFC applcation from CDialog to CDialogEx?I don't want  to create a new application i.e. i want to change my existing application

Comment: Find and replace all the occurrence of CDialog with CDialogEx

Comment: ofcourse i tried,  But that is not working.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: It is telling that it can't find base class CDialogEx

Comment: are you using visual studio 2010? include "afxdialogex.h"

Comment: install MFC Feature pack from the location http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6922

Comment: i included header and error is removed . But setbackgroundcolor is still not working

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8116/discussion-between-durgesh-t-and-jeeva)

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that you are using VC10 (Visual Studio 2010), and also ensure `v100` is set as Platform Toolset in project settings.
- Include `<afxdialogex.h>`, preferbly in `stdafx.h`

If you can't use `CDialogEx`, you may need to write `OnEraseBkgnd` and do background paining yourself, and would also need handle backgrounds of controls via `OnCtlColor`